# Automatically setting date time value for DateTime property to current date and time in asp.net models

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want to create `DateTimeCreated` and `DateTimeUpdated` properties in the following model. I want both fields hidden from the user when creating/editing a project on html page. `DateTimeCreated` property should be set to current date and time of the user's browser only once (when user creates a project for the first time), similarly `DateTimeUpdated` should be set to current date and time of the user's browser every time the user edits/updates the project. Is there a simple way to implement this?

```
public class Project
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateTimeCreated { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateTimeUpdated { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: I presume this data is being saved in a database or something similar.  Why not add these values in the backend?

Comment: indeed - this should be done at the backend - not the UI layer.

Comment: Using the user's browser date and time is a bad idea, if you don't store the time zone. Use the server time or, much better, UTC.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Into the Create function of controller use `DateTime.Now` to get current date and time

```
public ActionResult Create(Project project)
{
   SampleDb db=new SampleDb();

   // Add audit info
   project.DateTimeCreated = DateTime.Now; 
   project.DateTimeUpdated = DateTime.Now; 

   //Save entity
   db.Projects.Add(project);
   db.SaveChanges();
}
```

Comment: And similarly in `Edit` action set only `project.DateTimeUpdated` to `DateTime.Now`. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

**Just Old Way**

```
  private DateTime dateTimeUpdated = default(DateTime);
    public DateTime DateTimeUpdated
    {
       get
       {
          return (this.dateTimeUpdated== default(DateTime))
             ? this.dateTimeUpdated= DateTime.Now
             : this.dateTimeUpdated;
       }

       set { this.dateTimeUpdated= value; }
    }
```

Or

```
public class Project
{
    public Project()
    {
        this.DateTimeUpdated = DateTime.Now; 
        // This will be update in Init. Or assign as constructor param
        // Problem This will update in every init
    }

    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateTimeCreated { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateTimeUpdated { get; set; }
}
```